# App Activity Monitor

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is a requirment to log almost all activity of users of my MVC 5 App., i.e. on Create, Update and Delete for 7 tables.

There is almost 25 action-methods involved to manage partial update of those tables, I'm finding a way to log activities of all those action-methods without changing everywhere.

Any suggestion? how to achieve this?

Comment: Use [AOP](https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net) in order to inject code into desired method.

Comment: You could use a filter to log which avtion methods are getting invoked by the user. or if you need to log the changes the user makes you could log the changes tracked by ef.

Answer (score 0):

I would fire up a background logger worker (in a background/parallel task), and submit messages to it through a mediator of some kind.

You would have to keep ONE instance of your logger, singleton, and one mediator that can publish/subscribe.

One Implementation could be the use of the Prism Event Aggregator:

```
public class Logger 
{
   private IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

   public Logger(IEventAggregator eventAggregator){
      _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;

      // Register events to log
      _eventAggregator.GetEvent<Messages.MethodCalled>().Subscribe(() => LogMethodCall);
   }

   public void LogMethodCall(string information){
      // Do log things here
   }
}
```

This would require you to publish these events somewhere

```
public void DoSomething(){
   // other code

   // log it
   _eventAggregator.GetEvent<Messages.MethodCalled>().Publish("DoSomething called");
}
```

I hope you get the idea. This is a fairly clean, unobtrusive way of logging in a background task so that you don't steal any time from the main executing thread.